# XML within an XML field in JAX-WS

Tags: xml, jax-ws

I'm trying to include XML in an XML field for use in a SOAP call.  I'm using JAX-WS to make the call.

When I simply create a string with the xml in it, I see < get converted to `&lt;`, however > remains >.  I'm using Wireshark to see outgoing request and incoming response.

I've tried changing all of the < and > to `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively, however I end up with `&amp;`gt; and `&amp;`lt;.

What is the best way to go about including XML within an XML field?

Answer (score 0):

You would use `![CDATA[`

For example:

```
...
<someField>someValue</someField>
<someXML><![CDATA[<field1>value</field1><field2>value2</field>]]></someXML>
...
```